# module. is a object, known only after apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I'm trying to create a ssm parameter in aws for dyanamo db table with name and arn so it can be referenced by another application.  I've tried a few different things but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Thank you

Here's my main file with the module.

main.tf

```
locals {
  prefix = "/this/is/a/test"
}

module "test_table" {
  source = "git@github.com:test/terraform-modules.git//dynamodb"

  name                  = "dynamo-${local.environment}"
  ssm_parameter_prefix  = local.prefix

  tags = {
    Environment  = local.environment
  }
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "table_name" {
  provider = aws.east
  name     = "${local.prefix}/new/table-name"
  type     = "String"
  value    = module.test_table.name
}

resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "table_arn" {
  provider = aws.east
  name     = "${local.prefix}/new/table-arn"
  type     = "String"
  value    = module.test_table.arn
}
```

Here is the output

outputs.tf

```
output "test_table" {
  value = module.test_table
}

output "table_arn" {
  value       = module.test_table.arn
}

output "table_name" {
  value       = module.test_table.name
}
```

Terraform Error

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on dynamo.tf line, in resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "table_name":
│  118:   value    = module.test_table.name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.test_table is a object, known only after apply
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "name".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on dynamo.tf line, in resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "table_arn":
│  125:   value    = module.test_table.arn
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.test_table is a object, known only after apply
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "arn".
╵
```

Comment: Outputs have to be defined at the module level. Have you done that?

Answer (score 0):

The `output` blocks you showed declare output values named `table_arn` and `table_name`, but your references are to `module.test_table.name` and `module_test.table.arn`.

You'll need to either change the output value names to match the references, or change the references to match the output value names. Specifically, you'll need to either remove the `table_` prefix from each of your output value names, or *add* `table_` to the front of the references like `module.test_table.table_name` and `module.test_table.table_arn`.